# How to configure 1 Socket with multiple cores to Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I've got a Hyper-V 2012 running on a Windows 2008R2 Enterprice server and need to configure that my virtual CPU are based on one socket. So the guest is seeing one socket with e.g. 4 core. I've found some tool called cpu z should do that, but is the "correct" way of doing this?